# Why 0.123456789 == 12.3456789 / 100 is True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

I know the floating point issues and I've read some documentations and have some understanding on `Decimal` type.

For example: `.1 + .1 + .1 != .3` .

But why:

```
>>> 0.123456789 == 12.3456789 / 100
True
```

is `True` ? I expected `False`.

Because adding is inaccurate so I think division should also be inaccurate?

Comment: Why do you expect it to be false? It isn't a general truth that mathematical identities involving floating point values are *always* false.

Comment: @JohnColeman I don't know. Maybe because adding is not accurate so I think division also shouldn't be accurate? Well I am getting a little bit confused when I learn more about floating point.

Comment: You could expect a single operation to generally get you to the float value which is closest to the true value. In this case the float value corresponding to `0.123456789` is the closest float value to the result of taking the float value corresponding to `12.3456789` and dividing it by `100`. Exactly why this is the case would require looking at the details of the representations and the algorithm used for division.

Comment: It's a coincidence. Neither `0.123456789` nor `12.3456789` have exact binary representations, but the nearest binary representation of `0.123456789` and `12.3456789 / 100` just happen to match up.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Could you give me a counter-example that `a != b / 10 ** n`?

Comment: `12.345678912/100 == 0.12345678912` is false.

Comment: @JohnColeman many thanks to both of you! Well that counter-example solves my doubts. So it just *"but the nearest binary representation of `0.123456789` and `12.3456789 / 100` just happen to match up."*. Please consider writing an answer and I am happy to accept !

Comment: @MadPhysicist How do you check the binary representation of `0.123456789` and `12.3456789 / 100`? I want to know how to do it so I can check it by myself.

Comment: @Rick You can dump a float into a struct and read the struct as unsigned 64-bit. Or you can use C to do it (technically UB if you do it the easy way). Either way, you'll need to familiarize yourself with IEEE 754 format, which shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: @MadPhysicist There is an offical way to compare listing here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html , I am looking into it and going to try it now. I have 1 coincidence example(`0.123456789 == 12.3456789 / 100`) and a counter-example (`12.345678912/100 == 0.12345678912`)so I am good to go. :P

Comment: @Rick. I'm not sure that page actually shows you how to look at the bits of a float

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well, I am not familiar with IEEE 754 now and I try to utilize `as_integer_ratio`. `(12.345678912/100).as_integer_ratio()` gives `(8895999191635039, 72057594037927936)` and `(0.12345678912).as_integer_ratio()` gives `(4447999595817519, 36028797018963968)`. They are not equal and both results are irreducible (I use wolframalpha to prove the results are irreducible)  then I would conclude the underlying representation must not be the same. Poor man's way to find the truth. Btw, thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Not really an answer, but too long for the comments:

To explore this phenomenon, I wrote a simple program:

```
import random

def f(a,b,n):
    x = random.uniform(a,b)
    y = n*x
    return x,y,x == y/n
```

Then for example

```
trials = [f(0,100,100) for _ in range(10000)]
print(len([x for x,y,t in trials if t])/10000)
```

prints values like `0.8634`

I have tried a number of values for `a,b,n`, with `==` holding typically in the range 80% to 90%. A strange observation which confuses me:

```
f(0,100,100000000)
```

is much more likely to give rise to a counterexample than either

```
f(0,100,10000000)
```

or

```
f(0,100,10000000000)
```

I would have thought that for `a,b` fixed, the probability of `x==y` is monotonic in `n`, but it apparently isn't.

Comment: Thank you sir, the trial code is helpful and now I can find as many as counterexamples as I want.